# Images not displayed in Tab host

Tags: android, image, android-tabhost

In my application using Tab host activity and set the tab with pictures. While the application run on emulator the image are displayed without any problem. But it's not displayed while i run the application on mobile(Micromax mobile).

Please tell me what's the problem and How to resolve it.

Tab Host Codings:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WeekActivity.class);

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost
            .newTabSpec("Week")
            .setIndicator("Weekly", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_main))
            .setContent(intent));

    Intent intent2 = new Intent(this,ListMonthActivity.class);
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost
            .newTabSpec("Month")
            .setIndicator("Monthly", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_setup))
            .setContent(intent2));
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

    Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, ListYearActivity.class);
    TabHost.TabSpec spec=tabHost.newTabSpec("Year").setIndicator("Yearly",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)).setContent(intent3);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    /*tabHost.addTab(tabHost
            .newTabSpec("Year")
            .setIndicator("Yearly", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_setup))
            .setContent(intent3));
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);*/

    // Set tabs Colors
    tabHost.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    tabHost.getTabWidget().setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
   }
```

### Selector tab host Xml file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <!-- When selected, use grey -->
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/calendaricon"
      android:state_selected="true"/>
  <!-- When not selected, use white-->
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/calendaricon2" />
 </selector>
```

### Tabhost layout XML file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    >
    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
   </TabHost>
```

Comment: see this example you got idea @Venkatesh [http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablayout-example/](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablayout-example/)

Comment: show us some code snippet that you have used

Comment: Image displayed  on emulator and Samsung mobile. Not in micromax mobile .This is my problem. Please anyone help me to out of this problem.

Comment: And in micromax mobile the bottom buttons in an activity are also shrink their views . The buttons captions are not shown.

Comment: can you share the device specs such as screen dpi, size, model etc...

Comment: Operating System : Android v2.1 OS
600MHz CPU
Band : GSM 900&1800MHz – WCDMA 900/2100MHz
Weight : 105gms
Dimensions : 106.8×59.2x14mm
Large 2.8-inch touchscreen display , 320×240 pixel resolution
Gravity Sensors
Digital compass
3G HSDPA/HSUPA
WiFi
Bluetooth
miniUSB
150MB Internal memory

Comment: device model of your micromax device ?

Comment: which OS version did you have in your Samsung mobile ? which samsung device did you used there ?

Answer (score 2):

Either you have to save the images in each folder like mdpi,hdpi,ldpi with the same name or you have to just save the pictures in mdpi folder the low resolution or high dencity mobile automatically pick the images from mdpi foleder..

Comment: did you save the images with the same name

Comment: u don,t need to make seprate xml for each

Comment: i will suggest you not to make seprate xml file for each maybe your devise not pick the appropriate xml therefore it doesn't show u the images.Or did u try with the android default icon image if not just try with the android default icon image,

Answer (score 2):

When I gave below given code, it worked successfully.

```
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Bar").setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_barchart)), BarChart.class, null);
```

The change I made is, simply kept the first parameter of `setIndicator` as an EMPTY string. (When I gave it as `"BarChart"`, it didn't work.)

Answer (score 1):

Set image in the Tab Host as:

```
TabHost.TabSpec spec=tabHost.newTabSpec("hello").setIndicator("hello",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)).setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

i just tried this in the device and its working fine.